# Confusion with Ruby's `GC#start`

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

***Program - I***

```
p RUBY_VERSION

a = "A"
b = "B"

p "#{a}"
p "#{b}"

p "Garbage Count => #{GC.count}"

b = "D"

p "Garbage Count => #{GC.count}"

GC.start

p "Garbage Count => #{GC.count}"

p "#{a}"
p "#{b}"
```

*Output:*

```
"1.9.3"
"A"
"B"
"Garbage Count => 1"
"Garbage Count => 1"
"Garbage Count => 2"
"A"
"D"
```

In the `Program I` the output of `p "Garbage Count => #{GC.count}"` made me confused which are `1,1,2`.Confusion was with the `garbage objects` count. So I tried a modified version of `Program-I`as below.

Where I commented out `GC.start`. Now looking at the output of `Program -II` it seems
as I strated `GC.start` in my first program,which in turn destroyed the no-reference object
`"B"`.

***Program - II***

```
p RUBY_VERSION

a = "A"
b = "B"

p "#{a}"
p "#{b}"

p "Garbage Count => #{GC.count}"

b = "D"

p "Garbage Count => #{GC.count}"

#GC.start

p "Garbage Count => #{GC.count}"

p "#{a}"
p "#{b}"
```

*Output:*

```
"1.9.3"
"A"
"B"
"Garbage Count => 1"
"Garbage Count => 1"
"Garbage Count => 1"
"A"
"D"
```

***Final questions are:***

*(a) Before `GC.start` 1 object has been destryed which is clear from the output. What object was it?*

*(b) Why no-reference object `B` was not being destroyed without `GC.start` ?*

***EDIT***

```
p GC.count
p GC.disable
p GC.count
```

*Output*

```
1
false
1
```

in the abive code I have disabled `garbage collection`.Why does the last `GC.count` is showing the output as `1`?

Can anyone help me to understand the questions raised on my mind as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

GC.count doesn't return the number of garbage collected objects - it returns the number of times the garbage collector has run, so calling `GC.start` will always increment it by one.

A bunch of code gets executed before your code starts to run, so it's not that surprising that some garbage collection may occur.

Disabling gc isn't going to undo the garbage collections that have already happened.